# Unique tag count in a DataDog top list

Tags: datadog

I've a metric which has 2 tags (it has more but this is for simplicity), *client* and *rule*, and its value of course. With it I can see the total count of the values for each client, each rule and each ruleXclient.

Now I want to create a top list which would tell me the amount of unique clients per rule, so if the metric is reporting that 2 clients (2 values of the tag client) have 4 hits each for a rule (single value for the tag rule) I'd like the top list to show me:

*2: RuleA*

Is that even possible? How could I approach this if it isn't?

I'm using dogstreams to report the metric.

Comment: I contacted datadog support about the same use case. At the moment it's not possible